# Using KnockoutJS template within jQuery template

Tags: jquery-templates, knockout.js

I have a jQuery template, and I would like to use a KnockOutJS template within this.

I cannot make this work as this example illustrates: http://jsfiddle.net/maate/bwmcR/1/.

However, it DOES work when the KnockOutJS template itself is placed outside the scope of the jQuery template as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/maate/bwmcR/2/.

It seems that the problem is related to the scope of the template data variables (for instance, I can access the `${test}` variable within the `subTemplate`).

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Br. Morten

Comment: Can you clarify you question a bit..  you seem to have the code working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you have is just not valid. Although you want to create a sub-template it has to be in a separate script tag. You just can't embed templates within each other, you have to create them one after the other.
WRONG:

```
<script id="superTemplate" type="text/html">
...
<script id="subTemplate" type="text/html">
...
</script>
</script>
```

RIGHT:

```
<script id="superTemplate" type="text/html">
...
</script>
<script id="subTemplate" type="text/html">
...
</script>
```

When you applied the subtemplate on the ul, you defined what data it should be using with the foreach, so you won't be able to read the `test` as it is not a property on an item.
If you want you can pass it as a templateOption so it will be available on the subtemplate too.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'subTemplate', foreach: items, templateOptions: { testValue: 'Value' } }"></ul>
```

This way it will be available on the subtemplate.

```
<span data-bind="text: $item.testValue"></span>
```

Also, I wouldn't use the default jQuery template tags, it is much nicer with data-binding.

```
<div id="body" data-bind="template:{name: 'superTemplate'}"></div>
```

It will do the same, more or less, in the end. You can take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/bwmcR/18/